# Signup using facebook in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement signup/login using `Facebook` in my app. Currently I'm following the tutorial on `Facebook developer` [Login Ui tutorial on Facebook developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-ui-control/)

I have imported the `Facebook SDK` and the following code also works

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

Now what I require is

1) Change the `FBLogin` Button to my custom button

2) when the login is successful, I need to capture the users gender, email and profileid to store in the server for signup and also to validate if the user is already signin

3)Also need to know which all details should I store in session to fetch the users friendlist from `facebook`

If anyone has done it, please do help me with your guidance and source code.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Follow the new Facebook Tutorial, You will find everything you need:
[Facebook iOS Tutorial v 2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.